# How do I access Web Service via SOAP in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I tried something like this :

```
  try{

    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
            )
        );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $client = new SoapClient('http://83.166.204.26:7147/TEST/WS/Harmont%20Blaine_TEST/Page/WebItem?wsdl',
                             array('stream_context' => $context,
                                   'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

                             ));
    print_r($client);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and the result of my var_dump function is:
**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from .... failed to load external entity...**

how can i access the web service via soap ? thx.

This is the beginning of the xml :[image]

Comment: anyone ? any ideas are welcomed :)

Comment: I don't think you need user agent and context. It looks like you can't read WSDL because it is protected with basic authentication. See second part of my answer for solution

Comment: I saw from another posts that I have to enable extension=php_openssl.dll from php.ini. I have to mentioned that it was enabled from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: 
URL that you supply required Basic authentication. When using HTTP basic authentication, PHP will only send the credentials when invoking the service, not when fetching the WSDL.

[You CAN get a wsdl, if basic authentication is required](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#88902):

```
$login = 'xxx'; 
$password = 'xxx';

$client = new SoapClient(
     'http://' . urlencode($login) . ':' . urlencode($password) . '@83.166.204.26:7147/TEST/WS/Harmont%20Blaine_TEST/Page/WebItem?wsdl',
     array(
         'login' => $login,
         'password' => $password
     ) 
);
```

Secondly :
Your return XML does not look like valid WSDL file. Read [SoapClient documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) for proper usage - first argument of `new SoapClient()` must be URI of WSDL file or `null` for non-WSDL usage. (Here is an [example of WSDL file](https://acceptatie.parnassys.net/bao/services/cxf/v1/generic?wsdl) ) May be you need to create SoapClient in non-WSDL mode?

Comment: I updated my post. I think this is the link: http://83.166.204.26:7147/TEST/WS/Harmont%20Blaine_TEST/Page/WebItem?wsdl. This return valid WSDL

Comment: please check my post again

Comment: I used exactly your code, I just changed the password and login but I still get this message "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:".  Thx for helping me out , I really appreaciate it

Comment: in the browser it perfectly working, check my post to see what i get

Comment: It has to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the file from 83.166.204.26:7147/TEST/WS/Harmont%20Blaine_TEST/Page/WebItem?wsdl. I saved it on wsdl format and now i'm getting the functions

```
$client = new SoapClient("WebItem.wsdl", array('proxy_host'     => "83.166.204.26",
                                            'proxy_port'     => 7147,
                                            'proxy_login'    => "xxxxxx",
                                            'proxy_password' => "xxxxxxxx"));
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); echo "</pre>";
```